# boost::interprocess and circular_buffer , C++

Tags: boost, ipc, interprocess, circular-buffer

My English is approximate, I apologize for this inconvenience.

I am c++ developer and I would like to use boost::circular_buffer in my boost::interprocess program.

This following code compiles but there is a freeze at startup :

```
    managed_windows_shared_memory w_shm( boost::interprocess::create_only, "joffrey_app", 100);
    typedef char ValueType;
    typedef allocator<ValueType, managed_windows_shared_memory::segment_manager> allocator_char;
    typedef boost::circular_buffer<ValueType, allocator_char> ipc_circular_buffer;
    const allocator_char myallocator (w_shm.get_segment_manager());
    ipc_circular_buffer* w_shm_gecko = w_shm.construct<ipc_circular_buffer> ("from_gecko") (myallocator) ;
```

Thank you very much in advance for your answer.

Comment: In what way does that solution solve your problem?

Comment: If you have found the solution to your problem, make it an answer to your question, explaining why it solves the problem. Then you can (after two days) accept it, so that people can see the problem is solved.